# Index of the Closest point in an array each containing 3 elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find the index of the closest point in an array(pts) containing 3 elements each.
I have written the following code, but it does not return me the index of the closest points:- Would appreciate if anyone could please let me know where i. am wrong. Thanks!

```
void point_index(Point pts[], int &size)



}
cout << x << "   " <<  y << endl;
```

Thank you, everyone, for the help! I have figured out my mistake and corrected the code!

Comment: you are using `a` before it is initialized. Also, the `j` incrementation is useless and your function does not return anything

Comment: Why not `double a, min = get_distance (pts[0], pts[1]);` then `for... for... if ((a = get_distance(pts[i],pts[j])) < min) { ... } a = min;` (also, you can't return anything from type `void`, did you mean `Point point_index (...)`? you would need to keep a temp `Point` and set it to the minimum indexes and return that) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I have updated my code above, but it is still not printing the indices of the closest point.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   Thanks for the help! It worked!

Comment: Good job, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the minimum value in `min`, after compare store the minimum value in `min` and set distance value outside if to compare properly.

```
a = get_distance(pts[i],pts[j]);
if (a < min) {
     x = i;
     y = j;
     min = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the minimum, you need to assign x,y and min.
Try this code:

```
double a;
int x = 0, y = 1;

double min = get_distance(pts[x],pts[y]);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++) 
    {
        double d = get_distance(pts[i], pts[j]);
        if (d < min) 
        {
            x = i;
            y = j;
            min = d;
        }
    }
}
cout << x << "   " <<  y << endl;
```